# Disk not mounting after enabling TRIM

Tags: macos, ssd, mount, trim

I enabled the TRIM for my SSD on my MacbookPro using Chameleon SSD, and now the Mac doesn't boot any longer. I have tried to follow guides to reverse the TRIM but none of them actually work because my disk appears to be not mounted and does not appear in `/Volumes/`

When I open the Disk utility, the disk is greyed. If I try to mount it, I get an error : `Try repairing the disk`. And of course, when I run a repair, it fails too.

Sadly I have no recent backup (of course, would be too easy).

How can I mount this volume and reverse the TRIM enable?

Comment: Please can you tag in your OS version - Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Filevault2 / full disk encryption? If you are not sure, what does `diskutil cs list` yield in terminal?

Comment: and out of curiosity: what SSD do you use?

Comment: Hello, I am using Yosemite latest version. FileVault is disabled, no encryption.

Comment: I have used the Disk Warrior utility to fix the partition. Unfortunately, it has cleared the MACBOOK partition and replaced it by Untitled. I removed the drive from the Macbook and plugged it on a dock on my IMac; here what I see: http://s4.postimg.org/ct0sthczt/Capture_d_cran_2015_07_23_14_50_18.png The MACBOOK partition is greyed out. Cannot mount it

Answer (score 1):

Don't panic! I hope you haven't done irreparable damage with the disk utilities and partitioning, which has nothing to do with the problem. The fix is actually very simple.

The grey screen is caused by the non-signed kernel driver for the SSD. Mac OS X won't allow it to load by default, thus you can't access the boot disk.

This can happen if you don't turn off the kernel signing check, or if it gets turned on, which it often does during a system update.

If you are using Trim Enabler, this article describes how to recover. A similar procedure should work for anything that turned on trim.

I'm using a Crucial SSD too, with trim enabled. I forgot to turn Trim off before a system update, and had to recover using the instructions on the linked page (successfully).

Basically it overrides the kernel signing check once again, so you can boot your Mac like before.

https://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/

Once I was back in, I used the trimforce command to prevent the problem in the future ;-) Trimforce is new in Yosemite, I believe.

Comment: An earlier version of my answer proposed the same thing. But it seems the problem here goes deeper than that. OP cannot mount his Volume anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `fsck` as described in [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203176)?

1. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> at startup to boot single-user mode
2. In terminal `/sbin/fsck -fy`

If single-user mode doesn't work, try [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130306/45492):

1. In terminal: `df -hl` to find the disk in question.
2. then do `sudo fsck_hfs -l /dev/disk?`

NB: As described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181673/45492), OS X provides since 10.10.4 a new tool called `trimforce`, allowing users to activate TRIM also on unsupported disks. No more dangerous experiments with third party software necessary.

Comment: I have tried the fsck_hfs with -d (for repair) but repair fails.

Comment: @Axel I fell we are running out of options here. Maybe someone else has more ideas. What SSD do you have? There are some disks that do not properly support TRIM and might start writing garbage if activated.

Comment: It's a Crucial SSD 500Go. The disk itself works. I'm trying a data recovery on it. I can see the partition, I just have to figure a way to mount it or fix it