# External drive is damaged and freezes my Mac. Any way to recover?

Tags: partition, external-disk, hdd, damage

I'll explain everything in a clearer way.
I have a WD My Passport Studio external hd, since a while it's impossible to read it and here's the symptoms:

- When I mount it and try to open the main folder, it is empty, but I
  can see the content with ls from terminal.
- Every action takes a lot of time (like trying to fix it in Disk Utility) and always fails.
- I can't unmount it, it just doesn't and I have to reboot.

I think the partition is somehow damaged but I can't solve the problem. any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First Steps: Repair the Disk, Tell Us What Happens

What exactly is happening isn't something I know. However, with a damaged disk, the first step should be to attempt to diagnose/repair it. Since that didn't work, tell us what went wrong. It'll give us a lot of insight into what may have happened and how we can fix it.

### Since You Can't Repair The Disk

It's possible (although unusual) that using the command line fsck will help. Follow [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/how-can-i-repair-a-disk-that-disk-utility-says-it-cant-repair-this-disk) and let us know what happens.

### Command Line?

This doesn't seem like it should work, but if the disk is accessible from the command line, you could just use command-line copy paste. This doesn't seem like it should work, but you never know.

### Data Recovery

No one likes it, but you may have to just reformat your partition after taking it to a data recovery service.

Comment: I couldn't repair the disk so I had to copy everything from command line but was unsuccessful. Then I used diskdrill/diskwarrior to repair the partition but recovering data is too slow (some files takes like hours/mb) so i guess some blocks are physically damaged. is that right?

Comment: @Freddy It's likely, but it's difficult to tell. You may want to take it to a professional data recovery service, it's possible that you're doing more harm than good at this point then.