# How to create a bootable disk for an older Mac?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, external-disk, recovery

The file system on an older Mac mini (early 2009, latest supported OS 10.11) [got corrupt](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5247607), and disk utilities ended up in an infinity verify-can't-repair loop. Thanks to a [insightful tip](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153679/167899) I could mount it on a different machine and restore my files. (I physically removed the disk and mounted it with a USB-to-SATA cable).

I proceeded to reformat the disk, and now want to install a bootable macOS on this disk.

The best action seems to follow the Apple guide "[How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372)", which requires me to download macOS 10.11 (El Capitan). It's normally hidden in the App Store, but I found the [direct link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12). Unfortunately, I can't seem to download it on my new Mac: It gives me a warning "OS X can't be installed on "MyNewMac" because the version of macOS is too new.". I know, but don't want to run it, just install on the disk for the older Mac, so I can run it on the early 2009 Mac mini.

How to proceed?

Comment: By reformatting before acquiring the Installer, you've kind of locked yourself into a Catch22 - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/309399/85275 Your 'simplest' get-out would be to take it to an Apple Store & they'll do it for you [or find a friend who can access the EL Cap 'special' version.] Alternatively, that machine may be capable of Internet Recovery.

Comment: is this your link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12  Apple says ..To download it, your Mac must be using macOS High Sierra or earlier. Here is the problem ..After downloading, the installer opens automatically and it will not do that.

Comment: so the problem is .. The installer will automatically launch itself when the download completes. I do not know how to stop that and download without automatically wanting to start the installation.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - Read my linked QA. That El Cap link is already known to not work if the machine is capable of running anything newer.

Comment: @Tetsujin exactly, you are right, it wont even download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Note: A more complete and up to date answer to this question can be found at this link: [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

I tried your link https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12 and received the following error message. Assume your error message was the same.

[image: jj3]

### The answer below assumes the Mac is running High Sierra.

If you purchased El Capitan for free in the past, then you will find this recorded in your App Store account. Open the App Store application, then click on the Purchased button. Enter your username and password. If you purchased El Capitan in the passed, then El Capitan will appear in the list. You will be able to download even if the macOS is newer than El Capitan.

If El Capitan does not appear in your list of purchases, then try to find someone who has purchased El Capitan and use their username and password.

Comment: he already has a Link to app store that works. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12

Comment: @Buscar: It tried that link. I received an error message stating the download would not occur because I am running High Sierra. However, once logged in to the App Store, I could download El Capitan from my list of previously purchased items.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I've just been looking at this in Mojave, to add details to my 'older OS X' QA & older OSes are no longer even listed in Purchased, at all. The El Cap link comes up as 'not available'.

Comment: BTW, that El Cap link is already known to not work if the machine is capable of newer than El Cap - it is not a get out of jail free card. [also noted in my 'older OS X' QA] Purchase history was already the only way to get it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I just successfully download El Capitan from my list of previous purchases. I am using High Sierra so the download will not run. I would have to boot the other Mac (2013 iMac) to Mojave to see if El Capitan would still download.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I've added the current status, as far as I can determine, to the top of my linked QA. Seems like all old versions are gone from purchased.

Comment: @Tetsujin: So are you suggesting that if the mac is running Mojave, then High Sierra needs to be first installed to the external drive before downloading El Capitan to the external drive?

Comment: Thanks! I indeed get a different messages in the list of previous downloads, ("Your mac already has a newer version installed. Are you sure you want to continue?"), but at least it lets me download it! Your alternative, is sound -- ask a friend, though I would rather bring a USB stick and ask him/her to download it for me, instead of asking for a password :)

Comment: @DavidAnderson - in effect, yes. Previously 'purchased' OS installers are gone from Mojave purchase history . This entire QA is basically a duplicate of mine, I was just trying to clarify the situation as it stands.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Well, as soon as Mojave downloads and installs on the 2013 iMac, I will try to confirm that El Capitan will not download.

Comment: @Tetsujin: You are right. If the Mac was running Mojava, then the procedure would have been as follows: 1) Download High Sierra. 2) Transfer High Sierra to a flash drive. 3) Boot from the flash drive.  4) Install High Sierra to the external drive. 3) Boot from the external drive. 4) Login into the App Store. 5) Download El Capitan.