# How do I install macOS 10.11 El Capitan on a Mac mini (Late 2012)

Tags: macos, install, mac-appstore, mojave

I have an older Mac mini (mid 2011) which runs macOS 10.11, 10.12 and 10.13. It did not allow me to install macOS 10.14, so I had to order another (used) Mac mini (late 2012) that now runs macOS 10.13 and macOS 10.14 in separate partitions. Because running

```
$ hdiutil create -size <size>b <.dmg-file> -srcfolder <directory> -ov -format UDBZ
```

on macOS 10.14 creates a dmg file that can't be opened on macOS 10.11, we need to bundle our applications on macOS 10.11.

I've tried to create an image of the macOS 10.11 partition on the old Mac mini and restore it on the new one - it failed and reported about not having enough permissions.

I've tried several ways to download the installer of macOS 10.11, e.g. using the link on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886, but the App Store on the new Mac mini always tells me that my machine is too new, and the App Store on the old Mac mini simply tells me that macOS 10.11.6 "cannot be installed on this computer".

Is there a way to install macOS 10.11 on my newer Mac mini?

Comment: Have you tried all the options listed at [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: No, I haven't tried yet "Find a torrent/sharing site".

Comment: Have you previously purchased El Capitan from the App Store?

Comment: I don't know, but since I've had any macOS since 10.4, I reckon, yes. Since what time Apple offers the macOS versions for free?

Comment: If you have purchased El Capitan in the past, then you should be able to download  it from the App Store. The procedure is given in the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340623/how-to-create-a-bootable-disk-for-an-older-mac/340626#340626) to the question: [How to create a bootable disk for an older Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340623/how-to-create-a-bootable-disk-for-an-older-mac)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: After thinking about this a bit, it sounds like you may have some Mac minis that don't have the latest firmware updates.  Using the 2012 mini, do an Internet Recovery using Cmd-R and then upgrade from there.    You can verify your firmware version [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518)

Comment: So it is no sufficient to have a macOS 10.11 image from one machine and restore it on another?

Comment: @Thomas S."Yes it should be sufficient to have a macOS 10.11 image from one machine and restore it on another. You just did not do the transfer correctly. I never commented on this until now, because you never asked this question until now. Making statements about what you did in the past are generally ignored. Instead, I try to concentrate on the question that is actually asked. Also, if you wish to ask this question, then post a new question.

Comment: @Allan: If macOS 10.13 has been installed, then I would assume the firmware has been upgraded past anything that can be downloaded from the link you provided. In other words, I assume the macOS 10.13 installer would have upgraded the firmware beyond what can be downloaded from this link.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I don't assume anything, which is why I said, in my comment, *verify*.