# repair EXFAT external disk

Tags: hard-drive, partition, repair, exfat

My photos disk seems to have issues. Osx cannot mount it again. Also, the first aid utility is not successful

```
dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS Fotos                   2.0 TB     disk2s1

sudo fsck_exfat -d disk2s1
Opening /dev/rdisk2s1
fsck_exfat: Can't open /dev/rdisk2s1: Resource busy
```

How can I recover the data? Is it possible to repair the partitions?

### edit

I just found:

> [How can I repair a disk that Disk Utility says it can't repair?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130304/how-can-i-repair-a-disk-that-disk-utility-says-it-cant-repair)
>   You may not need to repair the disk!
>
> Is this an external drive you're sharing between a Mac and a Windows
>   PC? I've had this issue a few times with a disk formatted FAT32. If
>   you don't unmount your disk properly when you remove it from your
>   Windows PC, the whole volume will be marked as "busy" and you'll be
>   prompted to repair the volume if you look at it in Apple's Disk
>   Utility. However Disk Utility will fail to repair the volume, and
>   report: Can't open (Resource busy) File system check exit code is 8.
>
> The fix is easy, just plug that drive back in to a Windows PC, and
>   unmount it properly before plugging it into your Mac.

Comment: Did you eject the disk before you've started `fsck`?

Comment: Yes / unfortunately, they do not even mount in the first place

Comment: Interestingly, on WIN 10 it still can open the device. I will try to copy the data using windows to a separate disk then. However, I cannot get it to properly mount on osx. Still keep getting `device is busy error`

Comment: Try mounting it as read only from Terminal and then backing up the data. To do this, go to Terminal and type ```diskutil mount readOnly diskIdentifier|deviceNode``` and then see if you can get any data off of it. Then I would reformat and copy everything back.

Comment: Unfortunately, the WIN10 can show all the meta-information i.e. directory tree and so on, but it cannot open any of the files. It is also impossible to copy any data.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I tried Windows 10 own recovery tool. This one worked and could recover fix the issues.