MacOS can't repair ExFAT drive
Occasionally it happens that my 2TB external hard disk, formatted as ExFAT, suddenly gets unplugged (either by a n unfortunate movement of my hand, or by the cat, or whatever). There is no real corruption, because I don't do anything with the disk, but of course MacOS does not know this and complains that the disk is not properly mounted.
In most cases, neither mounting it or doing a "disk repair" in Disk Utility solves the problem. To my surprise, the "disk repair" tells me after less than one minute that it can't repair anything, no matter how often I try. But when I unplug the disk, and plug it into an old Windows 10 machine for repairing, it gets fixed: After an hour or so, the disk is repaired.
I would understand if MacOS takes a lot of time too, when reading the entire disk is necessary, but it decides quickly that there is no chance to fix it. What is so special with this problem, that Windows can do it, but MacOS can't?

Similar problems have been reported before: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388883/30895, https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/270850/30895, https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/226623/30895.

exFAT is a rather interesting file system... designed to accommodate high-volume storage systems, yet retaining the simplicity of the file allocation table (FAT) mindset. And in an unusual move, Apple made a decision to license exFAT software from Microsoft for integration in OSX. Of course Apple never used exFAT in their operating system per se; it was relegated for use with external memory devices. However, the exFAT file system is now widely used; for example, with SD cards.
Anyway, wrt your exFAT-formatted external drive, there are (at least) three issues that could be in play:

"exFAT was proprietary until 28 August 2019"

In 2013 Apple licensed the exFAT algorithm from Microsoft

Older versions of macOS, and other unlicensed applications may have used different implementations of exFAT.


All of which suggest that how and when you formatted your "2TB external hard disk" could play a role in your experience using it with macOS.
All that said, there is a command-line utility shipped with macOS that may help resolve your issues: fsck_exfat
You should probably read man fsck_exfat (and man fsck), which may lead you to the following command - run from Terminal.app. NOTE: Your "2TB external hard disk" should not be mounted when you run fsck on it:
% fsck_exfat -ygd <device, 2TB external hard disk>  

Note that <device, 2TB external hard disk> should be replaced by whatever device nomenclature your system has assigned to your "2TB external hard disk".
WRT your system's occasional complaints re "not properly mounted", I might suggest that you consider re-formatting your "2TB external hard disk" (after you back it up of course). I'd suggest you attempt this re-formatting using your macOS in an effort to minimize all of the vagaries noted above.
If you're interested in re-formatting your "2TB external hard disk", the following command may take care of that (otherwise see this recipe):
% sudo diskutil reformat <disk identifier>


Thanks for the suggestions. Actually, the reason why I was chosing exFAT is to have the hard disk readable and writeable under Windows and Linux.

BTW, I have formatted that disk around 4 years before, but on a slightly older MacOS version. I will give fsck_exfat a trie, when the problem happens next time.

@user1934428: You needn't wait for the next problem occurrence... most systems run fsck at each boot. However - one thing I forgot to mention is that your external drive must not be mounted when fsck is run.
